# Konqueror keeps uninstalling automatically

Tags: dolphin, automatic, konqueror

I keep installing this program and when I try to use it a few days later it invariably is no longer present and I have to reinstall it. Similarly, I keep uninstalling Dolphin, because it sets itself to automatically be the default file browser. The only way I could find to use the other file navigator by default was to uninstall Dolphin. However, I periodically find that Dolphin has automatically reinstalled itself and reappointed itself the default file browser.

Anyone know why this happens and how I can put a stop to it?

Comment: What release of Ubuntu have you got installed?  and is it installed, and not just run off a 'live' or usb-thumb-drive?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say. 18.04 is installed. It is not a live USB or anything, no. Regular installation.